# Intel Rst with multiple SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, intel-rst

Is there a possibility to cache one HDD with multiple SSDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge no. The software for the "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" also doesn't allow you to use more than 64 GiB as cache in the first place. You can "partition" SSDs bigger than 64 GiB to use up to 64 GiB as cache.

The SSD must have "a minimum capacity of 18.6 GB" according to Intel.

Quoting the limitations from the help:

- The maximum cache size is 64 GB.
- Only one disk or volume at a time can be accelerated per system.
- If two volumes are present on a single array (they share the same array of disks), neither volume can be accelerated.
- Once a volume is accelerated, a second volume cannot be added to the same array.
- Once a solid-state drive is configured to be used as a cache device, the option to create a recovery volume is no longer available. Recovery volumes do not support system configurations with multiple volumes.
- The maximum number of volumes allowed in the storage system is four. In the event that the combination of the solid-state drive configuration (data volume and cache volume) and system or data volumes reaches the limit, the application will not allow the acceleration of a disk or volume. You will need to delete one of the data volumes present in the storage system to enable acceleration on a disk or volume.